# Accessing GitLab CI Service from A Container running Inside DinD

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm trying to run a continuous integration in GitLab CI consisting of:

- build the docker image
- run tests
- push the docker image to a registry

Those are running inside one job. I can do it without any problem until come up some test that needs to communicate with database. My container can't communicate with Postgres services defined.

I've reproduce it in [a public repository](https://gitlab.com/hashlash/example-dind-service-gitlab-ci/-/jobs/201748932) with simple `ping` script

```
image: docker:stable

services:
  - docker:dind
  - postgres:latest

job1:
  script:
    - ping postgres -c 5
    - docker run --rm --network="host" alpine:latest sh -c "ping postgres -c 5"
```

The first script could run without any problem, but the second one failed with error

```
ping: bad address 'postgres'
```

How can I access the service?

Or should I run the test in a different job?

Comment: The second command of your script goes to service `docker:dind` so the alpine container is inside `docker:dind` and cannot see `postgres`

Answer (score 5):

The solution is to use `--add-host=postgres:$POSTGRES_IP` to pass over the ip address present in job container.

To find out postgres ip linked to the outer container you can use for example `getent hosts postgres  | awk '{ print $1 }'`

So the yml would look like

```yaml
image: docker:stable

services:
  - docker:dind
  - postgres:latest

job1:
  script:
    - ping postgres -c 5
    - docker run --rm --add-host=postgres:$(getent hosts postgres  | awk '{ print $1 }') alpine:latest sh -c "ping postgres -c 5"
```

---

To understand why the other more common ways to connect containers wont work in this case, we have to remember we are trying to link a nested container with a service linked to its "parent". Something like this:

```
gitlab ci runner --> docker       -> my-container (alpine)
                  -> docker:dind
                  -> postgres
```

So we are trying to connect a container with its "uncle". Or connecting nested containers

As noted by @tbo, using `--network host` will not work. This is probably because gitlab ci use `--link`  (as explained [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html#how-docker-integration-works)) to connect containers instead of the newer `--network`. The way `--link` works makes that the services containers are connected to the job container, but not connected with one another. So using host network wont make the nested container inherit postgres hostname.

One could also think that using `--link postgres:postgres` would work, but it also won't as in this environment postgres is only a hostname with the ip of the container outside. There is not container here to be linked with the nested container

So all we can do is manually add a host with the correct ip to the nested container using `--add-host` as explained above.

Comment: While this didn't work for me, I was able to get this working using `--add-host=postgres:host-gateway` instead. Not sure what was different about my setup, but posting here in case it helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `docker compose` for this.

Create a Docker Compose file `.gitlab/docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
services:
  test-runner:
    image: alpine:latest
    depends_on:
      - postgres

  postgres:
    image: postgres:latest
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: "${POSTGRES_DB:?}"
      POSTGRES_USER: "${POSTGRES_USER:?}"
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "${POSTGRES_PASSWORD:?}"
```

And your CI job can look like this:

```yaml
test:
  stage: test
  image: docker
  services:
    - docker:dind
  variables:
    COMPOSE_FILE: .gitlab/docker-compose.yml
    POSTGRES_DB: postgres
    POSTGRES_USER: postgres
    POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
  script:
    - docker compose run test-runner sh -c "ping postgres -c 5"
```